# Problem with HTML Agility Pack and Visual Studio C++

Tags: .net, c++, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am in need of a very simple HTML parser which can extract text, table from well-formed HTML documents in the .NET environment. I found several references to HTMLAgilityPack. My problem is that I am using the Visual C++ environment in the .NET framework. Can anyone help me with instructions on how do I add a "reference" to the C# generated .dll file into a VC++ project?
Is it even possible to use the HTMLAgilityPack in a Visual C++ Win32 Project? If you know a better/basic C++ parser that can do the task please let me know.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In visual studios you can add projects from multiple languages if you set the resource dependencies. I would add the htmlagilitypack project to the solution with my C++ project